# 2 monitors with sound, only 1 sound option

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-radeon

I used to use AOC I2476VWM that contains a 3.5mm jack output as the one and only monitor connected via HDMI (on both sides). Now, I added a Samsung TV as a second monitor. I reconnected the monitor to use DVI on the PC side and HDMI on the monitor side and used the HDMI port on PC for the TV (so HDMIs on both sides).

The problem is, the computer still displays the monitor only as a sound device (even though it's not even connected that way anymore) - you can see the Sound control panel [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxjJw.png) - so I can't send audio to the TV speakers. How can I play audio via the TV then?

What I tried:

- Set every option in the control panel as the default device.
- Change the main monitor so that the TV is the main one.
- Enable and disable different options.
- Reinstall the AMD Radeon drivers.
- Unplug the monitor altogether -> this one works! The Sound control panel then displays the same option (the TV icon and "AMD High Definition Audio Device") but named after the TV. But if I reconnect the monitor again, it switches back to it the next restart.
- Set only to display content on the TV or duplicate the screen -> this one also sometimes works. The other times it stop displaying any digital sound output. In case it's working, it still switches back after the restart.

I use:

- AMD A10 (I went through the AMD Radeon settings but I found nothing seemingly related)
- ASRock A88M-G/3.1 motherboard
- Windows 10 64-bit, version 1803
- AMD Radeon drivers 18.2.1

What I think is left to try:

- Connect the monitor through a DVI-VGA cable - I don't have one lying around at the moment
- Reinstall Windows - I'd like to do that as the last resort :)

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the GPU deployment, BIOS, or DVI port of the motherboard... Like the DVI port is really the "first" HDMI port with an internal converter to DVI for the back panel and when you connect a DVI monitor it thinks there is an HDMI sound device connected. Not sure how you could fix this. You could verify by booting a Linux distro on USB and duplicating the issue. I would try using VGA or a direct DVI connection to the first monitor, but I have a feeling this is a hardware glitch.